# Close active windows from the Terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line

I usually have multiple windows requiring to close before sleeping.
(all the contents are saved already)

I attempt to accomplish it in terminal so I can encapsulate commands to some script.

I tried:

```
$ close -a atom
-bash: close: command not found
$ close -a Opera
-bash: close: command not found
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Why do the windows need to close?

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means

Comment: close them let me comfortable to sleep @Mark

Comment: @JoseTronco Still don't understand why you need to use the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `osascript` to call an AppleScript from the command line.

Save the following script or [one like it](https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/document-close.html) somewhere, then run `osacript [path to file]`:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    close every document without saving
end tell
```